# Data is autodeleted from in-memory database

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb

I use HSQLDB for testing purpose. The problem is that when I add some data in `init()` method, then I can get that data only from the test which did run first.

```
@Before
public void init() {
    if(isRun)
       return;
    isRun = true;

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setId(1);
    role.setType("User");
    roleDAO.save(role);

    User user = new User();
    user.setCredits(1000);
    user.setEmail("User@test.com");
    user.setUsername("User");
    user.setPassword("qwerty");
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(roleDAO.findById(1))));
    userDAO.save(user);

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setCredits(1000);
    user2.setEmail("User2@test.com");
    user2.setUsername("User2");
    user2.setPassword("qwerty");
    user2.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(roleDAO.findById(1))));
    userDAO.save(user2);
}

@Test
public void findUserByIdTest() {
    User user = userDAO.findByUsername("User");
    assertEquals(userDAO.findById(user.getId()), user);
}

@Test
public void addUserTest() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setCredits(1000);
    user.setEmail("Antony@test.com");
    user.setPassword("qwerty");
    user.setUsername("Antony");
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(roleDAO.findById(1))));
    userDAO.save(user);

    assertEquals(userDAO.findByUsername("Antony"), user);
}

@Test
public void updateUserTest() {
    User user = userDAO.findByUsername("User");
    user.setCredits(0);
    assertEquals(userDAO.findByUsername("User").getCredits(), (Integer) 0);
}

@Test
public void removeUserTest() {
    userDAO.remove(userDAO.findByUsername("User"));

    assertNull(userDAO.findByUsername("User"));
}
```

So happens that `removeUserTest()` method always runs first and when I `findAll()` data then I see the data I set in `init()` method. After that, others test methods run but if I do `findAll()` there, it just returns nothing meaning no data exists. 
In addition, I have set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create.
What am I missing here? Why I can get data in the first running method but in others the data just disappears.

Comment: That's a spring test, right? It's expected: tests are transactional and the transaction is rollbacked at the end of each test by default. Even if you choose not to rollback, every test should be independant from the others, and should be able to run alone. You should not rely on the execution order either. Your findUserByIdTest() would fail if removeUserTest runs first. So, start by cleaning the database and to insert the test data before each test. If you rollback after each test, cleaning is not necessary, but you should still insert the test data before each test.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, that's a spring test. Thanks, you made it clear to me. The only issue that I face then is that when I add data, remove and then add again, the id property goes on incrementing(added data[id=1], removed, added again[id=2]. Therefore I can't rely on the id as it is constantly changed. Is there a way to refresh id programmatically?

Comment: I would just get the ID from the entity created in the initialize method. Or (shameless plug) use DbSetup: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html

Comment: @JBNizet I would get the ID from the entity created in the init method as well, but the problem is that every test id is changed because the entity is created and removed every test and id continues incrementing. So if the id initially was 1, then it would be 2, as it would be re-added with incremented id.

Comment: So what? If you use `user.getId()`, you get the ID of the inserted user. Whether it's 1, 2 or 12345 doesn't matter.

Comment: @JBNizet I meant that If I added a user into db in init method with id = 1 then let's say in `findByIdTest()` method I can't be sure that I will be able to find the user just using something like that: `userDAO.findById(1)`. I guess, it will only work if the added user in init method will be in global space so that I'll be able to get his id using `user.getId()`.

Comment: No, but you can make sure by using `userDAO.findById(user.getId())`. Yes, of course, you need to store the user, or its ID at least, in a field of the test class. You can also use DbSetup, and bypass the autoincrement when inserting the data, hard-coding IDs instead.

Comment: @JBNizet Brilliant, thanks a lot. You are welcome to give the answer so that I can accept it if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected: Spring repository tests are transactional and the transaction is rollbacked at the end of each test by default.

Even if you choose not to rollback, every test should be independant from the others, and should be able to run alone. You should not rely on the execution order either. Your `findUserByIdTest()` would fail if `removeUserTest()` runs first.

So, start by cleaning the database and to insert the test data before each test. If you let Spring rollback after each test, cleaning is not necessary, but you should still insert the test data before each test.

Incrementing IDs should not be a problem: you just need to stire the created entities or their IDs in fields of the test, and refer to these entities and their IDs instead of using hard-coded IDs in the test.